Передача Smarty вводных из формы методом POST с помощью JSON
Доброго времени суток всем!
http_referer: index.php?p=users, html отображение с помощью Smarty 5.x, передаются на сервер методом POST.
<form name="update" action="update.php?opt=gender" method="post" target="_parent">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
{foreach from=$users key=k item=i} <-- Массив из пяти пользователей
    <tr>
        <td>{$i.id}</td> <-- Id пользователя из массива
        <td>
            <select name="gender">
                <option>Select gender</option>
                <option value="man">Man</option>
                <option value="woman">Woman</option>
                <option value="donkey">Donkey</option>
                <option value="monkey">Monkey</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="family" value="{$i.family}">
            <input type="hidden" name="age" value="{$i.age}">
        </td>
        <td>{$i.name}</td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
<input type="submit" name="update" title="Обновить" value="Обновить">
</form>

Каким образом передать вводные как массив JSON для обработки на сервере?(с обработкой проблем нет, лишь бы дошло как массив) в доках по smarty xxx|@json_encode настолько скудно описано, что я честно не понял, поиск по стакам или гуглу (( ни одного примера не нашел. Помогите чайнику )).

Непонятно где в текущем коде планируется писать json... Ни одного поля вроде такого нет.... А в целом - можно спокойно на JS собрать данные  отправить

функция используется как обычный модификатор, пишите просто переменную которую надо вывести и применяете {$var|json_encode}, опционально туда еще через : можно аргументы натыкать.
зы синтаксис {foreaach $users as $i} сто лет как поддерживается

Алексей вот и мне не понятно, я же написал что чайник Я!
teran $var|json encode куда воткнуть если $var в name уже занят данными взятыми из существующего массива?
Если можно пожалуйста пример, на данной форме.

Мне кажется у вас проблема несколько не в том, что вы ищите.
вы выводите поля в инпуты с одним именем, в итоге и при отправке запроса, скорее всего получаете только последний элемент, наверное. Вам бы данные формы складывать в виде массива надо, и json_encode тут вроде как не при делах вообще.
Код генерации формы условно должен быть примерно такой (обращаем внимание на name у инпутов)
{foreach $users as $u}
<tr>
   <input type="hidden" name="users[{$u@index}][id]" value="{u.id}"/>
   <input type="text" name="users[{$u@index}][name]" value="{$u.name|escape}"/>

</tr>  
{/foreach}

То есть формируете массив с именем users и его получите в $_POST['users'] данных при отправке.
зы: есть вариант записи без {$u@index} но я что-то не помню как. Надо на каждой итерации  писать какую-то доп.строку для разделения элементов массива.

Спасибо )) Работает. если подскажете где копать доп вариант без {$u@index}, буду признателен

а хз, не могу найти. там какая то шляпа писалась типа type="hidden" name="users.index" value="{$u@index}" типа задавался индекс массива вручную (в начале каждой итерации перед заполнением полей нового объекта). Я более чем уверен, что где-то в просторах руСО среди моих ответов это есть, но найти не смогу )
